# ActionCable without upgrading to Rails 5 beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, actioncable

I currently have a Rails app running on 4.2.5, and I want to use ActionCable without having to upgrade the whole thing to the Rails 5.0.0.beta3 version and risk breaking all of the other gems.

Following guides I've seen on the internet, I've tried

`gem 'actioncable', github: 'rails/actioncable'`

which doesn't work because the ActionCable repo has been merged into the Rails repo. I even tried

`gem 'actioncable', github: 'rails/rails'`

but this doesn't seem to work of the re-numbering of the versions that happened when ActionCable merged into Rails. (The only version below 5.0.0.beta* is the 0.0.0, which seems to be an empty gem.)

I also tried setting the source to rubygems.org in hopes of finding an older pre-merged version, but was unsuccessful.

What can I do to integrate ActionCable into my 4.2.5 project without upgrading to Rails 5?

Conversely, when could we anticipate the first stable release of Rails 5? :)

Comment: You could try using the archive branch: gem 'actioncable', github: 'rails/actioncable', branch: 'archive'

Answer (score 0):

You can have both GemSets, so you can use rails 4 and rails 5 whenever you want.
First, update the ruby gem manager by `$ gem update --system`, install Nokogiri if you haven't `$ gem install nokogiri`.

Now lets set your rails 4 GemSet (you might have to update ruby, it will tell you if you need to)

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.3.0@rails4.2 --create
$ gem install rails --version=4.2.5
$ rails -v
```

your rails version should be 4.2.5 at this point.

Now lets set your rails 5 GemSet

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.3.0@rails5.0 --create
$ gem install rails --pre
$ rails -v
```

your rails version should be 5 beta3 at this point.

We are done, now you only need to change between GemSets, depending on your needs, by doing this.

for rails 4 use = `$ rvm use ruby-2.3.0@rails4.2`
for rails 5 use = `$ rvm use ruby-2.3.0@rails5.0`

Now, you can use and experiment rails 5 without risking your rails 4 gems and stuff.

You can do exactly the same for other Rails versions if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue,But i solved.just check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3bbNgHUlX8)

Just try your rails console

check your rails version `rails -v`

may be `rails (4.2.7.1)`

Then you need to check gem list, i mean `gem list -l`

Now you can see your all gem with versions.

Then you need to instsll `gem install rails -v 5.0.0beta2`

once installed rails check gem list, `gem list -l`

Then you can see `rails (5.0.0.rc2, 5.0.0.beta2, 4.2.7.1)`

You successfully installed `rails 5.0.0`

Then you do `bundle update`

Update all gem and supporting rails 5.0.0,this is work for me just try this.